# Cybersource Secure Acceptance test cards

Tags: cybersource

Does anyone know if there are test card numbers that simulate failed transactions for Cybersource secure acceptance? I have searched the docs and can only find successful payment card numbers

Answer (score 0):

Credit card numbers do not trigger errors. Instead it is usually the amount of the transaction. You can see a list of errors and their triggers here: https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-cybs-so-test-data/so_overview.html

Note that errors are grouped by the payment processor you are setup for. The default for a test account is Chase Paymentech.

Comment: Thank you, I read that. I thought there would be card numbers too like every other provider I have worked with.

Not to worry, I will have to come up with another solution!

Comment: new link https://developer.cybersource.com/docs/cybs/en-us/tms/developer/ctv/rest/tms/tms-create-request/tms-test-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use "4111111111111112" to trigger an invalid card number response. Source: [testing guide](https://developer.cybersource.com/hello-world/testing-guide.html)